# No se muestra el error de la conculta

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli, java-swing

Cuando me da un error la consulta:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conection, $a[$i]);
```

No me muestra en el navegador.

Comment: Hola. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar el mensaje de error.

Comment: Mejor agrega todo el código, no se sabe que contiene `$a[$i]`